# How to decode attribute cirrilic values use 'lxml xslt encode' from xml doc?

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml

After the conversion, there is a problem with the encoding of attribute values. Standard conversion does not help.

```py
import lxml.etree as ET
 
data = '<Response> <ОргМн Наим="ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ"> <Орг НаимЮЛПолн="НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ 5087"> <ГРНДата ГРН="5087" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18"/> </Орг> </ОргМн> </Response>'
 
rools = '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> <xsl:template match="/"> <xsl:copy-of select="*" /> </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>'
 
root = ET.fromstring(data)
xslt = ET.fromstring(rools)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(root)
 
result = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='unicode')
print(result)
```

```xml
<Response>
   <ОргМн Наим="&#x41E;&#x411;&#x429;&#x415;&#x421;&#x422;&#x412;&#x41E; &#x421; &#x41E;&#x413;&#x420;&#x410;&#x41D;&#x418;&#x427;&#x415;&#x41D;&#x41D;&#x41E;&#x419; &#x41E;&#x422;&#x412;&#x415;&#x422;&#x421;&#x422;&#x412;&#x415;&#x41D;&#x41D;&#x41E;&#x421;&#x422;&#x42C;&#x42E;"> 
      <Орг НаимЮЛПолн="&#x41D;&#x410;&#x418;&#x41C;&#x415;&#x41D;&#x41E;&#x412;&#x410;&#x41D;&#x418;&#x415; 5087"> 
          <ГРНДата ГРН="5087" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18"/>
      </Орг> 
   </ОргМн> 
</Response>
```

Try decode use `encoding='unicode'`, but no result.

How to get the following output?

```xml
<Response>
    <ОргМн Наим="ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ">
        <Орг НаимЮЛПолн="НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ 5087">
            <ГРНДата ГРН="5087" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18"/>
        </Орг>
    </ОргМн>
</Response>
```

Comment: Can you change the XSLT to add e.g. `<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8"/>` and the code to use e.g. `result = str(newdom)`?

Comment: What happens if you directly run `print(newdom)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now tested with Python 3 and lxml 4.9.1 that using

```
rools = '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8"/> <xsl:template match="/"> <xsl:copy-of select="*" /> </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>'
```

plus then simply

```
root = ET.fromstring(data)
xslt = ET.fromstring(rools)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(root)

result = str(newdom)
print(result)
```

gives the result

```
<Response> <ОргМн Наим="ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ"> <Орг НаимЮЛПолн="НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ 5087"> <ГРНДата ГРН="5087" ДатаЗаписи="2008-11-18"/> </Орг> </ОргМн> </Response>
```

Comment: I am ashamed of this mistake. The solution really helped me.